# How can I run my debugger commands while the program is running?

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code

I've configured my `launch.json` & `tasks.json` then return to my `file.c` and click the green arrow.

I see 'attached image'. Click OK to allow access then I am left with my Debugger but no variables exist and my options like `step_into`, `step_over` disappear then I find myself in the same loop.

Below is the JSON for launch and tasks.

`launch.json`:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "clang - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "clang build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

`tasks.json`:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "msbuild",
            "args": [
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/t:build",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "clang build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: Attached Image of where fail happens]

Comment: I would use GDB if you can. In my opinion, it's more usable out-of-the-box than VSCode.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Thanks for the reply, I am brand new to C and StackOverflow I've been working with VS Code since December completed TeamTreeHouse's Frond End Dev TechDegree :)

Did that tag work? it doesn't highlight your name

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't highlight display names, but I did receive a notification. Apparently your problem's been solved, though. Make sure to accept the answer that helped you by clicking the gray checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the code is not "paused", so the debugger will not activate while the code is actively running. Try to set a breakpoint and see if that fixes the issue.